# S3, from deep link to sub domain (bucket)

Tags: amazon-s3

I would like to redirect a link as www.example.com/test to a bucket called test.example.com on S3. As far as I know, Apache has a file called .htaccess that does the trick. I'm able to redirect from test.example.com to a bucket on S3, but I don't know how to do it with the deep link thing. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no way to accomplish that. I have seen many posts describing amazon s3 as a "very simple container". I solved my problem by creating a folder named test on the main bucket (www.example.com) with a html page redirecting to the actual bucket test.example.com. The best solution is to move to an apache container service, but for the moment I want to keep it simple.